# Zephyr USB device string descriptors definition

Tags: zephyr-rtos, usb-descriptor

the question is about USB device implementation in Zephyr OS.
We need to add interface string descriptor for ineterface name.
Using USBD_STRING_DESCR_DEFINE(primary) I've added that to string descriptor section, but it has index "0" - that's wrong (?) because it brakes basic string descriptor structure defined in usb_descriptor.c.
How we could setup defines/linker commands to add new USB strings after that ones in usb_descriptor.c?
Given example defines newly added string with index 0 (but it should be 4 - after manufacturer, product and serial num).

```
USBD_STRING_DESCR_DEFINE(primary) struct webusb_iface_descriptor webusb_string_descr = {
    /* webusb iface String Descriptor */
    .bLength = sizeof(struct webusb_iface_descriptor),
    .bDescriptorType = USB_DESC_STRING,
    .bString = WEBUSB_IFNAME,
};

void webusb_init() 
{
    int idx = usb_get_str_descriptor_idx(&webusb_string_descr);
    if (idx != 0) {
        webusb_desc.if0.iInterface = idx;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `USBD_STRING_DESCR_USER_DEFINE` rather than `USBD_STRING_DESCR_DEFINE`. `...USER_DEFINE` will add to the descriptors and `...DESC_DEFINE` will override the default ones that are included via `usb_descriptor.c`. I haven't been able to find any documentation talking about this but experimentally it works as I describe